# lessphp not compiling borders correctly?

Tags: php, less

I've just spent the last several hours trying to figure out why I was getting unhelpful errors, only to find that my variables weren't being imported because it didn't expect the include path to be the current directory (odd...) so I'm kind of worn out and hoping someone else can help me out here.

I'm using [this PHP LESS compiler](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) and it's working great for almost everything. It's just not liking lines like this:

```
border: 1px solid (@col-border / 3);
```

In this case, `@col-border` is defined as `#996633`. It correctly calculates it as `#332211`, but the resulting "CSS" is:

```
border: 1px solid(#332211);
```

Which, needless to say, doesn't work. Interestingly, it doesn't have this problem with other such lines, like this one:

```
box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px (@col-shadow / 3 * 4), -2px -2px 4px (@col-shadow / 3);
/* this compiles just fine */
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could look through it and find out where this problem is coming from. I'm just too exhausted to go digging myself right now...

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured it out.

Apparently, it was reading `1px solid (@col-border / 3);` as though `solid` were a function name and `@col-border / 3` its argument.

I edited line 2985 to disable the `$eatWhitespace` argument of `$this->match`, and now it respects the whitespace after the keyword. Of course, this means I can't use `function (argument)` syntax anymore, but does anyone ever use that?

Anyway, thanks for not downvoting me! :p

Answer (score 0):

### A Solution Not Requiring Edit of a Line of Code

I just thought I would offer a solution that does not require a line edit of the code itself. This works:

```
@col-border: #996633;
border: ~"1px solid"(@col-border / 3);
```

Outputs:

```
border: 1px solid #332211;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'd rather not have to hack around with my CSS just to make it seem to work, when I can make the actual code work properly in the first place ;)